# How to send lat and lng from onMyLocationChange to onMapReady?

Tags: google-maps, android-studio

I am designing a google map app for Android. in this app, i world like use user's latitude and longitude for calculation. however, i cannot use those data coz they cannot be apply in public void onMapReady.

I had tried for several ways, like:
1. Intent
2. SharedPreferences
3. Bundle
4. and even try to save those data to SQLite and get them in public void onMapReady.

All this methods seem to be useless.

```
 private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
        LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        if(mMap != null){
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 10));

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(loc)
                    .zoom(16)
                    .bearing(0)
                    .tilt(30)
                    .build();
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            getLocation = location;

            lat = getLocation.getLatitude();
            lng = getLocation.getLongitude();

            latitude = Double.toString(lat);
            longitude= Double.toString(lng);


        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.setTrafficEnabled(false);
    mMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
    mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

    mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);



    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
```

What can i do?

Comment: [onMapReady()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback) is only called when your map is ready to use. For example, when your map is show on screen. If you save your latitude and longitude to sharedPreferences first, then you can use the data in your `onMapReady()` when your map activity is created again (for example, your  app is killed and launch again). But if your map activity doesnt need to be created again, then the `onMapReady()` wont be called again. Also, in your code example, it does not show how you use the sharedPreference.